# visual studio 2015 WPF designer not loading stating System.ArgumentException An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

can someone please help me keep getting this error when trying to create my WPF solution and I need to beable to use my deigner for my studies thanks heaps.

```
System.ArgumentException
An item with the same key has already been added.

at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Telemetry.VsTelemetryService.RegisterDesignerProcessSession(Int32 pid)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.Feedback.WatsonTracker.RegisterSession(Int32 processID)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Utility.DesignerSessionTracker.RecordDesignerStart(Int32 processID, String isolationTargetIdentifier, Boolean mockCustomTypes, String buildConfiguration)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, String baseDirectory)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry, IServiceProvider serviceOverrides)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass10_0`1.<StartTask>b__0()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Identical problem reported on [this MSDN forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e42b3ff3-c35e-4ef9-84fc-a37b34a920b9/xaml-designer-in-new-wpf-project-throws-systemargumentexception-upfront-in-new-solution?forum=wpf). Answers there may help you.

Comment: I have seen that post cheers but no solution without reinstalling which I have already done today it worked for abit n stopped again

Comment: I have also tried a full uninstall and re-install without any luck. This problem is maddening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your target to x86 and recompile then close the window and reopen and the designer should work. Ensure your x86 platform has the correct values to target x86...

It appears to be an issue with x64. So we build under x86 and then flip and test x64. Annoying but at least you can get the designer to work.

Comment: I got it running again after a malware scan and found afew malware viruses but i will try that aswell this is a known issue by the sounds of the threads i have been reading ?? thanks for you reply kelly

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "Ensure your x86 platform has the correct values to target x86"?